# Performence analysis of routing metric in wireless mesh network (using AODV OR OLSR)

Tags: performance, networking, routes, ns2

can it be done using aodv protocol . using etx metric ect. i tried using OlSR but could not do it.here is the link that i followed http://www.inf.ufrgs.br/~wlccordeiro/resources/olsr/README.html  but it says olsr_parameter.h file which is not present in olsr folder when i installed.
 how can it be implemented in ns2.

Answer (score 0):

> olsr_parameter.h file

The file doesn't appear any more in the updated (2016) text, `README.md` https://github.com/wevertoncordeiro/olsr-ns2 ... The page http://www.inf.ufrgs.br/~wlccordeiro/resources/olsr/README.html ... was updated "February 26, **2010**, 8:58:13 PM".

The ETX sample, `script-olsr-etx.tcl` runs OK with the latest UMOLSR version. ( The @Weverton Cordeiro patch `olsr.patch` adds no changes at all to "UMOLSR latest" except for some lines with the name `Weverton Cordeiro` )

OLSR (UMOLSR), ns-2.35:

```
tar xvf ns-allinone-2.35_gcc5.tar.gz        ( 2014..2017 update )
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNVVlxR0ZNRGVORjQ/view?usp=sharing

```
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
patch -p0 < umolsr-ns235_v1.0-2014.patch
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNeVZhWFVVZlJnUEU/view?usp=sharing

```
./install
cd ns-2.35/
# make install
```

Examples, olsr-ex_02.18.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/17BUzR9siaKi0tsuWpeA6gMf02BItoi1N/view?usp=sharing

All ~3000 ns2 simulations https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing

All ~300 ns2 patches https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNZ2lWZDBRSW40Q00?usp=sharing